# How does matplotlib calculate the min / max axis values? Or how to automatically add the matplotlib margin when setting the limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, limit

When we plot a curve, matplotlib automatically adds some offset to the minimum and maximum points. How does matplotlib calculate this 'offset'?

E.g.

```
plt.plot(range(0,10))
plt.ylim()
```

gives the `y` limits `(-0.45, 9.45)`.
while

```
plt.plot(np.array(range(1,10))/100)
plt.ylim()
```

gives the `y` limits `(0.006, 0.094)`.
Not surprisingly, when I set axis

```
plt.plot(range(0,10))
plt.ylim(0,9)
plt.ylim()
```

I get `(0.0, 9.0)`.

Often I want to set limits, but still want some margin on the limit, e.g. when the limit is on a line, the line should be nicely displayed.

Of course I can add some fraction when setting the `y` limit but this always requires some tweaking. I am wondering if there is a smarter way to do it.

Comment: If no margin is provided matplotlib automatically adds a 5% margin to your x/y limits

Comment: Is the question on how matplotlib does it, or on how you can reproduce the same behaviour when manually changing the limits of a chart?

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous it's on how to reproduce it, e.g. when setting limits I want to have the default margins added.

Comment: @DavidG what do you mean by 'if no margin is provided'? Are you referring to setting `mpl.rcParams['axes.ymargin']` other than the default `0.05?

Comment: You can set the margins yourself using [`plt.margins`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html) (or `ax.margins`), if you don't call either of those then the value applied to your plots will be that of `mpl.rcParams['axes.ymargin']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @DavidG 's comment, we add the correct amount by using the margins `plt.margins()` or `ax.margins()`.

Taking the given example in the question:

```
d = range(0, 10)
plt.plot(d)
ymarg = (max(d) - min(d)) * plt.margins()[1]

plt.ylim(min(d) - ymarg, max(d) + ymarg)
plt.ylim()
```

which returns `(-0.45, 9.45)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I can find in the source, the margin is set as a fraction of the data range with the [`axes.xmargin`/`axes.ymargin`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/99d19f7ffb67324218e9d0a288346c8a1ccbee43/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L1221-L1222) parameters, but the [computation is rather more involved](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/99d19f7ffb67324218e9d0a288346c8a1ccbee43/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L2629-L2761).